# Hide Navigation Bar without Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationbar

I want to hide a `UINavigationBar` that is not inside of a `UINavigationController` (it's a modal view) when a button is pressed.

How can I do this? I'd like it to be animated.

Comment: Why don't you just use the navigation controller ? It just makes every thing so much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be animated you can just set its alpha down to 0.0

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Hide bar animation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

then back to 1.0 to unhide it

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Show bar animation" context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
navigationBar.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Although in iOS 4+, the use of the block animation methods is encouraged

```
+ (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

which you can use like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            animations:^{ 
                navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;
            } 
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                /* some completion code */
            }];
```